# Wordpress: Which user submitted post for review?

Tags: php, wordpress

Suppose 2 different contributors submit 2 different posts for admin review, can we find out which contributor pushed which post for review?

If so, where is this information stored in the DB?

Actually, I want to list all posts that were 'submitted for review' by a particular contributor.

Comment: in the table `wp_posts`

Comment: Are you using a plug-in or something?

Comment: @Joren under which column? post_author,
post_date,
post_date_gmt,
post_content,
post_title,
post_excerpt,
post_status,
comment_status,
ping_status,
post_password,
post_name,
to_ping,
pinged,
post_modified,
post_modified_gmt,
post_content_filtered,
post_parent,
guid,
menu_order,
post_type,
post_mime_type,
comment_count,

Comment: @RobertRozas No, no plugins.

Answer (score 1):

In the `wp_postmeta` table, there is an entry called `_edit_last` which gives the ID of the last editing user for a given post. If you want a query that returns all pending posts for a given author ID, regardless of author, you could use something like this:

```
$params = array(
'post_status' => 'pending',
'meta_key' => '_edit_last',
'meta_value' => user_id
); //Change user_id to the author's ID

$pending_posts_edited = new WP_Query($params);
while($pending_posts_edited->have_posts()) : $pending_posts_edited->the_post(); ?>

//Loop as you normally would

<?php endwhile; ?>
```